# Finding the value of $\alpha$ such that P is a measure for $P(\{2,3 \})$

Tags: probability

Question: Find $\alpha$ so that P is a measure, where:

$\Omega = \{1,2,3,4 \}, \mathscr{F} = P(\Omega), P(\{1 \})=\frac{1}{4}, P(\{2 \})=\frac{1}{6}, P(\{2,4 \})=\frac{1}{2}, P(\{3 \})= \alpha$

What is $P(\{2,3 \})$?

Here's my attempt:

Given

$\Omega = \{1,2,3,4 \}, \mathscr{F} = P(\Omega), P(\{1 \})=\frac{1}{4}, P(\{2 \})=\frac{1}{6}, P(\{2,4 \})=\frac{1}{2}, P(\{3 \})= \alpha$

We need to find $\alpha$ and $P(\{2,3 \})$

Since $\mathscr{F} = P(\Omega) = 1$ and $P( A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$, let $P(A)=\{1,3 \}$, $P(B)=\{2,4 \}$, then

$1=P(A \cup B)$

$1=P(\{1,3 \}) + P(\{2,4 \})- P( \{1,3 \} \cap \{2,4 \})$

$1= P(\{1 \}) + P(\{3 \}) + P(\{2,4 \})- 0$

$1= \frac{1}{4}+ \alpha + \frac{1}{2}- 0$

$1= \frac{1}{4}+ \alpha + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{2}$

$1= \frac{1}{4}+ \alpha + \frac{2}{4}$

$1= \frac{3}{4}+ \alpha $

$1- \frac{3}{4}= \alpha $

$\frac{4}{4} \cdot 1- \frac{3}{4}= \alpha $

$\frac{4-3}{4} = \alpha $

$\frac{1}{4} = \alpha$

So, $P(\{3 \})= \frac{1}{4}$

Now, let $P(A)=\{1,3 \}$ and $P(C)=\{2,3 \}$. Then,

$1=P(A \cup C)$

$1=P(A) +P(C) -P(A \cap C)$

$1=P(\{1,3 \}) +P(\{2,3 \})-P(\{1,3 \} \cap \{2,3 \})$

$1=P(\{1 \}) + P(\{3\}) +P(\{2,3 \})-P(\{ 3 \})$

$1=\frac{1}{4} +P(\{2,3 \})$

$1-\frac{1}{4} =P(\{2,3 \})$

$\frac{4}{4} \cdot 1-\frac{1}{4} =P(\{2,3 \})$

$\frac{4-1}{4} =P(\{2,3 \})$

$\frac{3}{4} =P(\{2,3 \})$

I am not sure if I'm on the right track or if there's more to be done since there are 4 elements in Omega, then there's $2^4=16$ elements.

So does this mean I have to find measures of all 16 elements or just take some cases to shorten the process?

Comment: Is it assumed that $P$ is a probability measure?

Comment: And $P\{2,3\}=P\{2\}+P\{3\}=1/6+\alpha=1/6+1/4=5/12$

Comment: yeah but I had to find alpha first and then try to get P(2,3) but I just got lost. :/
Doesn't the entire sample space have to add up to 1? 
CONFUSED @_@

Comment: I asked about this yesterday and I had to use $  P( \Omega) = P(A)+P(B) -P(A \cap B)$ to find alpha. 
Then once I found alpha, I treated the $P(2,3)$ as an unknown by letting it be x on scratch paper. So I ended up with $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: well you have got $\alpha$, so you could use it. Also, it’s not in the definition of a measure $\mu$ that $\mu(\Omega)=1$ (and there’s counter-examples, take $\mu=2P$ for any probability measure $P$, then $\mu(\Omega)=2$ but $\mu$ is also a measure.)

Comment: wait a sec...maybe P isn't a probability measure. I don't recall using mews, but I do recall seeing $P( \Omega) =1$ and $P( \emptyset)=0$ as part of a definition. P must be something else.

Comment: In the second calculation you are missing $4$, so the union probability is not $1$.

Comment: @N74 that's p(4) right?  I calculated that to be 1/3 when I did 1=p(1)+p(2)+p(3)+p(4) because the sample space must add up to one.

Comment: @N74 maybe I should have calculated p(2,3) + p(2,4) or p(2,3)+p(3,4)

Comment: Still those sets does not cover the universe... So the probability of their union is not 1.